# Self-adjointness and pseudodifferential inverses on non-complete manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, operator-theory, riemannian-geometry

I would like to better understand the relationship between self-adjointness, pseudodifferential operators, completeness, and positivity in the following context.

Let $D$ be an elliptic differential operator acting on a Riemannian manifold $M$ (or a bundle over it). Consider $D$ as an unbounded, densely defined symmetric operator on $L^2(M)$, with initial domain $C_c^\infty(M)$.

If the Riemannian metric on $M$ was complete, then $D$ would be essentially self-adjoint. But if the metric is not complete, then my understanding is that $D$ could fail to have a self-adjoint extension.

However, I would like to look at this from the point of view of pseudodifferential operators, which is where my confusion lies.

I'm wondering if the following assertions are correct:

1. Even though $M$ is non-compact and not complete, there exists a pseudodifferential operator $(D+i)^{-1}$ of order $-1$ defined using symbols.
2. $(D+i)^{-1}$ does not necessarily extend to a bounded operator on $L^2(M)$ because $M$ is non-compact and not complete.

Additionally, I would like to know if the following is true:

3. If we know that $D\geq 0$, then it has a self-adjoint extension by Friedrichs' extension theorem. Then the pseudodifferential operator $(D+i)^{-1}$ would indeed extend to an operator in $\mathcal{B}(L^2(M))$.

I'm a bit suspicious of 3, because it seems to imply that $D$ would then be essentially self-adjoint in that case.

Comment: I think you may be looking at this backwards.  Typically when a symmetric operator fails to be essentially self-adjoint, the problem is that it has *many* self-adjoint extensions (and the closure of the operator is not one of them).  In particular for 3, the Friedrichs extension may not be the only self-adjoint extension, and may not be equal to the operator's closure.

Comment: An instructive example is to take $M = (0,1)$ and $D = -d^2/dx^2$.  You can get two different self-adjoint extensions by imposing either Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions (and it is the former which corresponds to the Friedrichs extension).  You can also explicitly determine the closure of $D$ and see that it equals neither of these (in some sense it imposes "both kinds" of boundary conditions simultaneously) and is not self-adjoint.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge for your explanation. I think one thing I'm particularly confused by, even if $D$ has many self-adjoint extensions, is what the relationship is between the operator $T_1=(D+i)^{-1}$, formed via functional calculus of the Friedrichs extension, and the pseudodifferential operator $T_2=(D+i)^{-1}$. For example, is $T_1$ given a Schwartz kernel (maybe even the same Schwartz kernel as $T_2$)? How could one try to answer this question?

Comment: The question to ask yourself is, what is the domain of each of them?